# Counting the occurences of character in a filesystem tree

Tags: grep, find, exec

The task was to find the number of occurrences of character 'a' in all files in the directory (recursively).

My script was this

```
find . -type f -exec grep -o 'a' {} \; 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

but it failed: I got result 0 even on my local computer it worked.

What's wrong with this script?  I guess it isn’t bulletproof or something. How could I make it bulletproof or correct?

Comment: it works on my computer. Did you try that: `find . -type f | xargs grep -o 'a' 2>/dev/null | wc -l` ?

Comment: "my computer" refers to computer at school ,and yep i tried xargs , which also worked on local pc

Comment: Did you have the correct permissions set ?

Comment: What operating system is the computer running? Also, when things fail, remove the `2>/dev/null` so you can see error messages. Finally, are you sure there are files with `a` in them in the directory you are running the command from?

Comment: You don't need the find: `grep -ro 'a' .|wc -c`

Comment: Why is everyone using `grep [...] | wc` when `grep -c` exists?

Comment: @DopeGhoti - because `grep -c` counts matching lines not occurrences.

Comment: Fair point.  I sit corrected.

Comment: @trolkura: Does your grep support the `-o` option?  `echo abc| grep -o b` should output `b` - if not, then you're using a grep that doesn't support that option (it's a non-POSIX extension to standard grep).

Comment: yes i does support -o

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problematic machine's `grep` does not support -o.

If this is the case, then your command line is generating an error message each time `find` execs `grep`. However, with standard error redirected to /dev/null, the cries fall on deaf ears.

`wc` does not receive a single byte, resulting in a line count of 0, because `grep` is exiting immediately.

Try running your pipeline without a stderr redirect, or with the redirect to a log file. If I am correct, you should see one error message per file found by `find`.

In case you find it useful, here's an alternative that does not use `grep`:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | tr -cd a | wc -m
```

If your `find` supports the more efficient `+` exec alternative:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | tr -cd a | wc -m
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
find "${directory-.}" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r cat | grep -F -o 'a' | wc -l
```

which is pretty much the same as your command, and got non-zero result.  Are you in the directory you thought you were?  And are you actually searching for `a`?  If not, I suggest `grep -F` (as I've used) or `fgrep`, to search for a fixed string rather than a regexp.

You can simplify further with `grep -r` (recursive grep):

```
grep -Fro 'a' "${directory-.} | wc -l
```

Unfortunately, you can't get `grep` to do the counting, as `grep -o -c` counts lines rather than occurrences - I consider that a bug.

Comment: It would return `0` if `grep` on that particular setup didn't support `-o`. Also `-c` means `Write only a count of selected lines to standard output` - not sure where is the bug...

Comment: @don_crissti - I mean it's a bug in the specification of `grep`.  It would be more useful for `-c` to be interpreted as "the number of lines which would have been output" in this case, making `-o -c` distinct from `-c` alone.  `-c` is specified by POSIX, but `-o` is not, so this interpretation wouldn't affect conformance (though it's probably too late to change now).  Perhaps "defect" is a better word than "bug"?

Comment: I think it does what it's supposed to do and I think this is the normal/expected behaviour - `gnu grep` manual is even more explicit: `Suppress normal output...etc` so `-c` cancels out `-o` just like `-q` cancels out `-c`.